# Passing a reference to a private array

Tags: php

I must admit that all the confusion out there about PHP's "pass by reference" has affected me and now I'm unclear. I would have thought the following code:

```
class TestClass {

    private $my_precious = array ('one','two','three');

    public function &give_reference() {
        return $this->my_precious;
    }

}

$foobar = new TestClass();
$my_ref = $foobar->give_reference();
$my_ref = array ("four", "five", "six");

echo print_r($foobar,true);
```

would print:

```
TestClass Object
(
    [my_precious:TestClass:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => four
            [1] => five
            [2] => six
        )

)
```

but alas, my reference seems to have no staying power and it instead just echo's:

```
TestClass Object
(
    [my_precious:TestClass:private] => Array
        (
            [0] => one
            [1] => two
            [2] => three
        )

)
```

How can I make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to assign by reference as well:

```
$my_ref =& $foobar->give_reference();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
class TestClass {

    private $my_precious = array ('one','two','three');

    public function & give_reference() {
        return $this->my_precious;
    }

}

$foobar = new TestClass();
$my_ref = & $foobar->give_reference();
$my_ref = array ("four", "five", "six");

echo print_r($foobar,true);
```